# Grep from text file over the past hour

Tags: grep, ping, cat

I have several commands similar to:

`ping -i 60 8.8.8.8 | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong" >> /security/latencytracking/pingcapturetest2.txt;` done

output:

> Tue Feb  4 15:13:39 EST 2014: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=50
>   time=88.844 ms

I then search the results using:

```
cat /security/latencytracking/pingcapturetest* | egrep 'time=........ ms|time=......... ms'
```

I am looking for latency anomalies over `X` ms.

Is there a way to search better than I am doing and search over the past 1,2,3, etc. hours as opposed to from the start of the file? This could get tedious over time.

Comment: I'd suggest dumping the data into a database. `(timestamp, pingtime)` and then you can hack 'n mangle that data any way you want. doing it with just grep at the command line will be ugly, especially if you want to check a time period that isn't a nice "easy" figure. e.g. "all dates Feb 15" is easy. "last 45 minutes and 10 seconds" is extraordinarily ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to your log, and then search based on that:

```
ping -i 60 8.8.8.8 | while read pong; do 
   echo "$(date +"%s"): $pong" >> log.txt
done
```

Your log will have entries like:

```
1391548048: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=47 time=20.0 ms
```

Then search with a combination of `date` and `awk`:

Using [GNU Date](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#date-invocation) (Linux etc):

```
awk -F: "\$1 > $(date -d '1 hour ago' +'%s')" log.txt
```

or [BSD Date](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) (Mac OSX, BSD)

```
awk -F: "\$1 > $(date -j -v '-1H' +%s)" log.txt
```

The command uses `date -d` to translate english time-sentence (or `date -v` for the same task on BSD/OSX) to unix timestamp. `awk` then compares the logged timestamp (first field before the `:`) with the generated timestamp and prints all log-lines which have a higher value, ie newer.

Comment: When I run the awk, i get the following error
    usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>>  <<<
awk: bailing out at source line 1

Comment: I'm guessing you're on OSX? Sorry, question didn't specify OS and I wrongly assumed GNU (Linux). Will check for an alternate solution for OSX/BSD.

Comment: @Waitkus - added version for OSX/BSD.

Comment: that got the past hour, I am trying to find anomalies of response times over 1000ms, can that be added?

Comment: @Waitkus, not sure what you mean. Did you read BSD Date manpage as linked above, and play with different values to `-v` ?

Comment: I added grep to your command to get the desired output, 
' awk -F: "\$1 > $(date -j -v '-1H' +%s)" log.txt | egrep 'time=........ ms|time=......... ms' ' this gives me the output over the past hour with any responses over xms

Comment: I was talking about ping response time over  1000ms not time range to search. Sorry for my lack of description.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with R:
1. I'd slurp the whole thing in with read.table(), drop the unnecessary columns
2. then do whatever calculations you like
Unless you have tens of millions of records, then R might be a bit slow.

Plan B:
1. use cut to nuke anything you dont need and then goto the plan above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with bash. You can compare dates, as follows:

Crop the date field. You can convert that date into the number of seconds since midnight of 1st Jan 1970

```
date -d "Tue Feb 4 15:13:39 EST 2014" '+%s'
```

you compare that number against the number of seconds you got one hour ago,

```
reference=$(date --date='-1 hour' '+%s')
```

This way you get all records from last hour. Then you can filter after the length of the delay